# Azure CosmosDB IS_DEFINED vs NOT IS_DEFINED

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I was trying to query a collection, which had few documents. Some of the collections had "Exception" property, where some don't have.
My end query looks some thing like:

```
Records that do not contain Exception: 

**select COUNT(1) from doc c WHERE NOT IS_DEFINED(c.Exception)**  


Records that contain Exception: 

**select COUNT(1) from doc c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.Exception)**
```

But this seems not be working. When NOT IS_DEFINED is returning some count, IS_DEFINED is returning 0 records, where it actually had data.

My data looks something like (some documents can contain Exception property & others don't):

```
[{
  'Name': 'Sagar',
  'Age': 26,
  'Exception: 'Object reference not set to an instance of the object', ...
},
{
  'Name': 'Sagar',
  'Age': 26, ...
}]
```

Comment: Are you doing count in docDB? Please do provide full queries, not just fragments.

Comment: select COUNT(1) from doc c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.Exception)

Comment: And tried this one as well: select COUNT(c.I'd) from doc c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.Exception)

Comment: I've seen docdb count doing weird things as well. have you tried counting on client side? I also suggest you create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including minimal number of sample documents and indexing structure) to get better answers.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I've updated question now, with full query & sample data.

Answer (score 6):

### Update

As Dax Fohl said in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717753/azure-cosmosdb-is-defined-vs-not-is-defined/47762412?noredirect=1#comment111972684_47762412) `NOT IS_DEFINED` is implemented now. See the the cosmos dev blob [April updates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/april-query-improvements/) for more details.

To use it properly the queried property should be added to the index of the collection.

Excerpt from the blog post:

> Queries with inequality filters or filters on undefined values can now
> be run more efficiently. Previously, these filters did not utilize the
> index. When executing a query, Azure Cosmos DB would first evaluate
> other less expensive filters (such as =, >, or <) in the query. If
> there were inequality filters or filters on undefined values
> remaining, the query engine would be required to load each of these
> documents. Since inequality filters and filters on undefined values
> now utilize the index, we can avoid loading these documents and see a
> significant improvement in RU charge.
>
> Here’s a full list of query filters with improvements:
>
> - Inequality comparison expression (e.g. c.age != 4)
> - NOT IN expression (e.g. c.name NOT IN (‘Luis’, ‘Andrew’, ‘Deborah’))
> - **NOT IsDefined**
> - Is expressions (e.g. NOT IsDefined(c.age), NOT IsString(c.name))
> - Coalesce operator expression (e.g. (c.name ?? ‘N/A’) = ‘Thomas’)
> - Ternary operator expression (e.g. c.name = null ? ‘N/A’ : c.name)
>
> If you have queries with these filters, you should add an index for
> the relevant properties.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between IS_DEFINED and NOT IS_DEFINED is the former utilizes the index while the later does not (same w/ = vs. !=). It's most likely the case here is IS_DEFINED query finishes in a single continuation and thus you get the full COUNT result. On the other hand, it seems that NOT IS_DEFINED query did not finish in a single continuation and thus you got partial COUNT result. You should get the full result by following the query continuation.

Comment: Just to get a count, you don't need to get full result set.

Comment: I think you down voted him for nothing. The RU cost would be the same as for scanning every raw of data. The SQL analogy would be: IS_DEFINED - indexed search, NOT IS_DEFINED - a table scan. Table scans are extremely RU expensive in Cosmos Db.

Comment: Jep, as of now this is totally correct. So currently one really should not use `NOT IS_DEFINED` for performance queries. See also here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/38164036-index-to-cover-for-missing-property-not-is-define

Comment: @Reitffunk thanks for the link, and note that the link *now* says they have implemented a fix!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the return value of IS_DEFINED.

The query will looks like this

```
Records that do not contain Exception: 

SELECT COUNT(1) from doc c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.Exception) = false


Records that contain Exception: 

SELECT COUNT(1) from doc c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.Exception) = true
```

Hoping somebody will find this useful.